# Combining 2 Variables with Unusual Correlation

Tags: regression, linear-model

I am doing a project where I use a linear model to calculate how much influence different parameters have on city bird populations. A recent [study](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fevo.2020.00058/full) produced very significant results that I want to incorporate into my analysis, but I am not sure how.

The study showed that relative brain size (RBS) and brood value (BV) are very good predictors of how well a bird species survives in cities, but only when used together in a unusual way. Species preform well in cities either have very high RBS and BV, or very low relative RBS and BV. [Figure 2](https://www.frontiersin.org/files/Articles/499977/fevo-08-00058-HTML-r2/image_m/fevo-08-00058-g002.jpg) describes the results very well.

I need to include the results of this paper in my analysis, but I have no idea how to incorporate them into a linear model. If I put RBS and BV into the linear model as separate parameters, I am fairly certain my model will be completely inaccurate. I need to somehow combine RBS and BV into a single parameter, but I have no idea how to do that. I don't have a lot of experience with nonlinear models, but from my understanding I would still need to somehow combine these two parameters in order to produce accurate results.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct: linear regression won't work well here.

Your options are: transform the features, or use a different type of regression. (And, of course, kernel-based methods are "a different type of regression" that actually are implicitly transforming the features, so that's always an option.)

For this particular problem, one thing you can do is to convert your inputs from `[x, y]` to `[x*x, x*y, y*y, x, y]`, which allows you to express any quadratic function over these two dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll go look more into nonlinear regression right away. I do have 2 follow up questions though. First, what do you mean by 'transform the features'? Second, Figure 2 has negative values because z-value are being plotted. Normally, RBS and BV are always positive. Can I still use the inputs you suggested?

Comment: "Transforming the features" means taking the feature vector, and producing a new one. For example, replacing two features by their sum. In this case, we introduce a bunch of new features. Other typical transformations are dimensionality reduction, replacing values by quantiles, ...
And yes, this works for all values of RBS and BV. You can express any quadratic function of RBS and BV with the features in my answer.